# Rails Postgresql - synonym dictionary somewhat not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, dictionary, synonym

I have a Rails4 app with Postgresql(PG_search) on a MAC. I created the synonym dictionary through rails migration. The synonym dictionary is somewhat working. Setup below

**Migrations**

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY custom_synonyms_for_keywords ( TEMPLATE = synonym, SYNONYMS = synonyms_for_keywords );
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_syns_keywords (copy=simple);
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_syns_keywords ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword WITH custom_synonyms_for_keywords;
```

**my_synonyms file:**
    fshk bim24os
    fridge  refrigerator
    postgres    pgsql
    postgresql  pgsql
    indices index*

**Controller**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   pg_search_scope :pg_search, against: :sku,
         using: {
           tsearch: { prefix: true, dictionary: "simple_syns_keywords" }
         }
end
```

**When i run**

```
Product.pg_search("fshk") # returns record of "bim24os"
Product.pg_search("fridge") # returns no record of "refrigerator"
```

**But when i run this, it returns the correct value**

```
SELECT ts_lexize('custom_synonyms_for_keywords', 'fshk');  # returns "bim24os"
SELECT ts_lexize('custom_synonyms_for_keywords', 'fridge');    # returns "refrigerator"
```

**RESULTS**

```
Product.pg_search("fshk")
   Product Load (3.0ms)  SELECT "products".*, ((ts_rank((to_tsvector('simple_syns_keywords', coalesce("products"."sku"::text, ''))), (to_tsquery('simple_syns_keywords', ''' ' || 'fshk' || ' ''' || ':*')), 0))) AS pg_search_rank FROM "products" WHERE (((to_tsvector('simple_syns_keywords', coalesce("products"."sku"::text, ''))) @@ (to_tsquery('simple_syns_keywords', ''' ' || 'fshk' || ' ''' || ':*')))) ORDER BY pg_search_rank DESC, "products"."id" ASC
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#Product id: 1, sku: "BIM24OS"]

Product.pg_search("fridge")
   Product Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "products".*, ((ts_rank((to_tsvector('simple_syns_keywords', coalesce("products"."sku"::text, ''))), (to_tsquery('simple_syns_keywords', ''' ' || 'fridge' || ' ''' || ':*')), 0))) AS pg_search_rank FROM "products" WHERE (((to_tsvector('simple_syns_keywords', coalesce("products"."sku"::text, ''))) @@ (to_tsquery('simple_syns_keywords', ''' ' || 'fridge' || ' ''' || ':*')))) ORDER BY pg_search_rank DESC, "products"."id" ASC
=> ActiveRecord::Relation []
```

I'm i missing a step because i'm not sure why it's not working.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please show the SQL query that Rails generates for both Product searches. Also, please show the original `CREATE` statements for `my_synonyms`.

Comment: i updated the question with the results from rails

Comment: Did you add fridge later?  I believe the dictionaries are cached per connection - does restarting your console change the results?

Comment: i restarted the console and same result but i tried something different. i flipped the values to fshk > refrigerator and fridge > bim24os. fridge now works but fshk doesn't anymore. so it's acting funny on the word 'refrigerator'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by adding "simple" in the third line of my SQL migration.

**From**

```
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_syns_keywords 
  ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword 
  WITH custom_synonyms_for_keywords;
```

**To**

```
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_syns_keywords 
  ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword 
  WITH custom_synonyms_for_keywords, simple;
```